# showing data in gridview from database

Tags: android, gridview

Does anyone know how to put the database entries into a gridview in android? Or is there a tutorial out there which explains how to do that.plz help me by giving complete example.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html).

Answer (score 1):

1. You need [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) for works (create, delete) with DB.
2. You need [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) for get data from DB and return it to adapter.
3. You need [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) or [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) for fill cells of GridView.